# How to improve site title search results

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, query-string

I'm a developer/designer for a community driven website: http://www.thegamesdb.net

**The problem we have is quite straight forward:**

*Pac-Man is a game on the site.  A person should be able to search "pacman" or "pac man" and the "Pac-Man" result should be shown. Currently, this does not happen.*

Search code snippet is below but full code can be seen at: http://code.google.com/p/thegamesdb/source/browse/trunk/tab_listseries.php

```
if ($function == 'Search')
{
  $query = "SELECT g.*, p.name FROM games as g, platforms as p WHERE GameTitle LIKE '%$string%' and g.Platform = p.id";
  if(!empty($sortBy))
  {
    $query .= " ORDER BY $sortBy, GameTitle ASC";
  }
  else
  {
    $query .= " ORDER BY GameTitle";
  }
}
```

I'm not that familiar with coding search techniques, so any help would be appreciated... I've tried searching around on the net and all I've found is some pre-fabricated site search engines. We do not really want to go down this route... it's a little overkill for our needs.

Looking forward to some discussion,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a string comparison feature called SOUNDS LIKE. This may be a good use case for it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

You would probably modify like so:

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE SOUNDEX(column) LIKE CONCAT('%', SOUNDEX($search_string), '%')
```

Comment: SOUNDEX basically removes whitespace, vowels, and duplicate letters that are next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is a perfect, lightweight solution to our problem and will work nicely for now :)

After reading Randy's post i had a play with Atomboys Double metaphone mysql function.... but it just caused my dev server to crash.

This is a nice hassle-free solution that fits in with our existing code.

Answer (score 0):

ultimately, you will need to decide how to perform a fuzzy match.

for your example - you might consider removing all whitespace, and any '-' character - then perform the `like '%$string%' match`.  you might also consider `UPPER` on both sides of that `LIKE`.

you can do more or less in your own way of determining fuzziness.